# Is there a way to know what Windows version is running in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, windows-8.1

I have an scenario where I need to know if I'm running Windows 8.1 (and not any other Windows version), using Node JS. Is there a way to figure out this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`os`](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html) module:

```
var os = require('os');

os.platform();
os.release();
```

For Windows `os.platform()` returns `win32`, so you can use:

```
if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
  console.log(os.release());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but os.release() returns 6.3.9600. This 6.3 is the same value for Win 8.1 as well as Server 2012 R2. I need to be able to differentiate between those two.

Comment: Looking at the source code of Node.js, I don't think it's possible to distinguish Windows and Windows Server. At least not with the os module.